# Do singleton classes create problems in a multi-threaded app?

Tags: ruby

This might be premature optimization, or premature over-cautionization, but I'm avoiding using singletons on a few classes because I'm concerned that down the road I'll need to run my app as multi-threaded, and that the singletons will create conflicts and messiness.  Do singletons have this issue in Ruby, or is there some kind of built in namespace so that when an a class refers to the singleton, only the singleton on the same thread is returned?

Edit: to clarify these are observable classes which when updated cause the other classes that are watching them to update.  I'm not sure if this is thread safe or not, but I do know that right now I'm passing these observable classes around a ton and it's kind of annoying.  And they do seem like natural singleton classes.

Comment: Shared scope (singleton or not) can causes problems in a multi-threaded app.

Comment: ^ that! The singleton ruby mixin itself is thread safe in terms of "you get the same instance in all threads, guaranteed." as Michael Kohl already wrote. However, keeping "your" singletons implementation thread safe is your responsibility.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All classes that aren't written to be thread-safe will cause problems in a multi-threaded environment, regardless of whether they're singletons or not.

The fact that your class is a singleton could make the problem worse, because it's shared by default.  You can't have an instance per-thread.

If the singleton state is read-only and immutable you won't have a thread safety issue.

If shared state is modified, you have to ensure that it's thread safe.

Comment: Immutable my not be specific enough in this case.  It may be a class that only exposes read only access to data but modifies its internal state underneath.

Comment: If it modifies its internal state, then it's not immutable.

Answer (score 11):

Here is an example of making a singelton threadsafe. You have to treat it like any other object which has state (`@things`) and is not immutable (readonly). The getters and setters need to access the internal state via a Mutex (mutual exclusion).

```
require 'singleton'

class MyObject
  include Singleton

  def initialize
    @things = []
    @mutex  = Mutex.new
  end

  def add(thing)
    with_mutex { @things << thing }   
  end

  def things
    with_mutex { @things }
  end

  def clear
    with_mutex { @things.clear }
  end

  def self.add(thing)
    instance.add(thing)
  end

  def self.things
    instance.things
  end

  def self.clear
    instance.clear
  end

  private

  def with_mutex
    @mutex.synchronize { yield }
  end
end
```

Further reading: http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_threads.html

Comment: I believe calling Mutex.new in methods will lead to racing condition when two threads could start initialising it simultaneously overwriting the @mutex variable.

Comment: Incrementing a number and appending to an array does not seem to produce any race conditions in Ruby 2.6.1. I tried different number of threads and none of them produced a race condition. I ended up with the same question in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969551/why-no-race-condition-in-ruby.

Answer (score 3):

The `Singleton` Ruby mixin itself is thread safe. It means that you are guaranteed to get the same instance in all threads, and only that! It doesn't mean that methods which you implement for a singleton class by yourself will be thread safe.

If you look at the `Singleton` module [implementation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/lib/singleton.rb) you'll see that `#instance` method uses `Thread::Mutex#synchronize` to guarantee thread safety of the method itself and also your class `#initialize` method. However, keeping your own singleton methods implementation thread safe is **your** responsibility!

Answer (score 2):

Although this seems like a case of [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAGNI), the [Singleton class](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/singleton/rdoc/index.html) does require `thread` and states the following in the docs:

> Klass._instantiate?() - returning ``the instance’’ or nil. This hook
>   method puts a second (or nth) thread calling Klass.instance() on a
>   waiting loop. The return value signifies the successful completion or
>   premature termination of the first, or more generally, current
>   "instantiation thread".

Does that help?