# Why no race condition in Ruby

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I was experimenting with multithreading examples. I am trying to produce a race condition using the following code. But I am always getting the same (correct) output.

```
class Counter
  attr_reader :count
  def initialize
    @count = 0
  end
  def increment
    @count += 1
  end
  def decrement
    @count -= 1
  end
end
c = Counter.new
t1 = Thread.start { 100_0000.times { c.increment } }
t2 = Thread.start { 100_0000.times { c.increment } }
t1.join
t2.join
p c.count #200_0000
```

I am able to observe the race condition in Java using much less number of iterations in each thread. Is it that I am not running it enough number of times to produce a race condition, or `+`/`-` are Thread safe in Ruby? I am using ruby 2.0.0p247

Comment: I would expect this because you are always incrementing the counter. The value of c is in the same location for both threads and it can be incremented there. An interesting test would be to time each thread separately and then time them together. Is it what you would expect? Just throwing around ideas

Comment: The situation is more complex with simple math operations due to some optimisation on e.g. `+=` whereby the call to allow GIL to switch threads is never made. See my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574254/generating-a-race-condition-with-mri?rq=1

Comment: Your code also **does** show a race condition in Ruby 1.8.7 (MRI and REE), JRuby and Rubinius - I just demonstrated this on my machine. The answer you accepted is specific to MRI Ruby 1.9+ (which is most popular). If you want to write truly thread-safe Ruby, you should treat it just like your Java example (your familiarity with Java threads *will* help), and not make any assumptions about the GIL.

Comment: What about JRuby (9.1.13)? I thought it was supposed to provide real threads (and not use the GIL), but I get the same results as with MRI 2.4.1 (i.e. consistent count unless I simulate race as per answers below).

Comment: *Update on my previous comment:* Shot myself in the foot. I was running the code using the shebang, so it wasn't actually using JRuby. Once I used JRuby by switching to it w/ rvm and doing `ruby ./counter.rb` it worked as expected. I would just delete the comment, but the time is up.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is because MRI Ruby threads are not really parallel due to GIL (see [here](http://www.igvita.com/2008/11/13/concurrency-is-a-myth-in-ruby/)), at CPU level they are executed one at a time.

Each command in a thread is executed one at a time hence `@count` in each thread is always updated correctly.

Race condition can be simulated by adding another variable like:

```
class Counter
    attr_accessor :count, :tmp

    def initialize
        @count = 0
        @tmp = 0
    end

    def increment
        @count += 1
    end


end

c = Counter.new

t1 = Thread.start { 1000000.times { c.increment; c.tmp += 1 if c.count.even?; } }
t2 = Thread.start { 1000000.times { c.increment; c.tmp += 1 if c.count.even?; } }

t1.join
t2.join

p c.count #200_0000
p c.tmp # not 100_000, different every time
```

A nice example of race condition is given [here](http://www.rubyinside.com/does-the-gil-make-your-ruby-code-thread-safe-6051.html), copied below for completeness

```
class Sheep
  def initialize
    @shorn = false
  end

  def shorn?
    @shorn
  end

  def shear!
    puts "shearing..."
    @shorn = true
  end
end


sheep = Sheep.new

5.times.map do
  Thread.new do
    unless sheep.shorn?
      sheep.shear!
    end
  end
end.each(&:join)
```

> Here's the result I see from running this on MRI 2.0 several times.
>
> $ ruby check_then_set.rb => shearing...
>
> $ ruby check_then_set.rb => shearing... shearing...
>
> $ ruby check_then_set.rb => shearing...
>   shearing...
>
> Sometimes the same sheep is being shorn twice!

Comment: If I understand it correctly, adding more statements to increment method should also produce race condition, right? I just tried that but I am not able to produce it.

Comment: adding more statements will not necessary produce race conditions, as long as the variable accessed is updated for both threads.

Comment: Thanks...but what I meant to say was that it might produce it, right?

Comment: the race condition won't be produced by adding extra statements to your original code without changing how variables are accessed. The problem is not the time taken in each thread.

Comment: One very simple addition: Ruby threads since version 1.9.3 typically time slice at 100ms. Which means 100,000 iterations of simple code will rarely trigger a race condition. The threads are not even running concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has a [global interpreter lock](http://ablogaboutcode.com/2012/02/06/the-ruby-global-interpreter-lock/). Everything that happens *in Ruby* is essentially synchronized. So the issue you are referencing that you encounter in lower-level languages like Java—where two threads might read the same value and collide with each other on `+=`—isn't an issue.

Where the `Thread` class comes in handy is when you are writing code that takes things outside Ruby land, e.g., with file or network I/O, making system calls, or interfacing with a C library through bindings.

Comment: Only true for Ruby MRI 1.9+.

Comment: @NeilSlater: Are you saying Ruby 2.0 got rid of the GIL? I hadn't seen that anywhere (though not saying you're wrong—I could have just missed it). A reference would be appreciated.

Comment: No, hence the `+`, but probably I could have been clearer. Only true for Ruby MRI 1.9.x and 2.0.0. I tested OPs code in all the versions I have installed. MRI 1.9.3 and 2.0.0 behaved as per the question, but the others did not. In fact the majority of major Ruby versions (as opposed perhaps to the  majority of Ruby in use) do not behave as the OP experienced.

Answer (score 1):

This would be due to Ruby 2.0's **Global Interpreter Lock**.

In a nutshell, any operations that aren't IO (such as File read/writes) will happen synchronously because of the underlying implementation of the Ruby interpreter.

See:

- [Does Ruby Enterprise use Green threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714837/does-ruby-enterprise-use-green-threads)
- http://merbist.com/2011/10/03/about-concurrency-and-the-gil/
- http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/7766043-interview-brian-shirai-on-rubinius-2-0-the-gil-and-thread-safe-ruby-code

Comment: I'd suggest also add the excellent http://www.jstorimer.com/blogs/workingwithcode/8085491-nobody-understands-the-gil

Answer (score 1):

Very simple way to see race condition happening in Ruby:

```
i = 0
2.times do
  Thread.new do
    30_000_000.times do # this should take more than 100ms
      a = i + 1
      i = a
    end
  end
end
puts i # the value will always be different
```

Examples with no race condition:

```
i = 0
2.times do
  Thread.new do
    10_000.times do # this should take less than 100ms
      a = i + 1
      i = a
    end
  end
end
puts i # 20000, always!
```

.

```
i = 0
2.times do
  Thread.new do
    30_000_000.times do # it doesn't matter how much time it takes
      i += 1
    end
  end
end
puts i # 60000000, always!
```

Comment: I can get the race condition for this if I run this on Ruby 1.9.3, but not Ruby 2.4.1. And I get non-deterministic for even the plain, single-assignment if I use JRuby 9.13 (and it's slower than any of them, strangely enough). So the lesson I've learned is that you'd better really know your Ruby version and how it handles threading if you're going to do anything with threads and care about having expected behavior and performance.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to understand this too and am getting different results for c.count in this code (copied from above). For example I get c.coint = 1,573,313 or 1,493,791 etc. Looking at the code, it seems that c.count should be 2,000,000 each time!

```
class Counter
    attr_accessor :count, :tmp

    def initialize
        @count = 0
        @tmp = 0
    end

    def increment
        @count += 1
    end
end

c = Counter.new

t1 = Thread.start { 1_000_000.times { c.increment; c.tmp += 1 if c.count.even?; } }
t2 = Thread.start { 1_000_000.times { c.increment; c.tmp += 1 if c.count.even?; } }

t1.join
t2.join

p c.count # Varies e.g. 1,573,313 or 1,493,791 etc
p c.tmp # Also varies: 882,928 etc.
```

Answer (score -1):

In case of Java you can get the race condition in asynchronous thread only.. It might be useful to find the exact solution what you need..