# Simple script which tries and fails to introduce a race condition

Tags: ruby, multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, thread-safety

I'm trying to understand concurrency vs parallelism.

My understanding is that concurrency has race conditions when threads depend on shared state. For example if N threads simultaneously pop from a shared input array and push to a shared output array, there is some risk that the output array will contain duplicates.

I know the Ruby interpreter is designed to prevent such behavior, but conceptually, am I right to understand that the possibility is still there and additional precaution should be taken if total atomicity is required?

I tried to create an example which shows a race condition but wasn't able to. I'm wondering if there is some simple code to create a race condition to show the limits of concurrency (vs parallelism, which as I understand is atomic).

Here's the attempt - This takes about 4 seconds to run and uses about 25% CPU on my i5 processor. Doesn't use much memory.

```
module AtomicityTestWithConcurrentThreadsAndGlobalVariables

  # parameters
  Thread_count = 10_000
  Method_calls_per_thread = 10
  Global_in_count = Thread_count * Method_calls_per_thread

  # global stores
  Global_in = 1.upto(Global_in_count).to_a 
  Global_out = []

  # base method
  def base_method
    Global_out.push Global_in.pop
  end

  # threads
  def n_threads(n, &blk)
    n.times.map { Thread.new &blk }
  end

  # consistency check
  def consistency_check
    "uniq length: #{Global_out.uniq.length}, total length: #{Global_out.length}"
  end

end

# init
if __FILE__ == $0
  include AtomicityTestWithConcurrentThreadsAndGlobalVariables
  n_threads(Thread_count) do
    Method_calls_per_thread.times { base_method }
  end.each &:join
  puts consistency_check
end
```

Please let me know if I'm thinking about this in the wrong way. Can multiple threads be expected to share global state in a atomic way, so trying to find a race condition is pointless?

Something else weird about this is that ruby 1.8.7 is way faster than ruby 2.3.0.

```
> rbenv global 1.8.7-p370

> time ruby test.rb
uniq length: 100000, total length: 100000
0.18user 0.01system 0:00.24elapsed 81%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 21100maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+10495minor)pagefaults 0swaps
13:00:34, taken:36, load:1.53, /home/max/Documents

> rbenv global 2.3.0

> time ruby test.rb
uniq length: 100000, total length: 100000
1.72user 0.38system 0:02.28elapsed 92%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 74680maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+54022minor)pagefaults 0swaps
13:00:41, load:1.64, /home/max/Documents
```

It's taking 0.01 system seconds with 1.8.7 and 0.38 with 2.3.0

Comment: I haven't analyzed your code closely, but since you didn't say what Ruby implementation(s) you tested on, I wanted to point out that there are some Ruby implementations which are actually incapable of running Ruby Threads in parallel, most notably MRI, YARV, and very old versions of Rubinius. Running concurrency and parallelism tests on implementations that don't actually support parallelism may indeed yield non-intuitive results.

Comment: @JörgWMittag thanks for the tip. It's regular ruby `2.3.0` and `1.8.7-p370` on x64 ubuntu.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19969551/why-no-race-condition-in-ruby

Comment: I finally got around to running your code on JRuby, and got this: "uniq length: 99980, total length: 99989".